# I can't make this to work, program that transforms an image into ASCII art

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want Help with my code because I can't make it work properly.
The part where I am struggling is when the image is being resized to 300x300.
When I upload an image less than 300x300 it works like a charm, but when the image needs to be resized it shows that :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KAYL\Documents\Python\ASCII\ascii.py", line 20, in <module>
    value = image_nb.getpixel((x, y))
  File "C:\Users\KAYL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1315, in getpixel
    return self.im.getpixel(xy)
IndexError: image index out of range
```

I just want the variable `image_original` to be resized and saved to `image`

Here's my code :

```
import io
import easygui
from resizeimage import resizeimage
import webbrowser

image_path = easygui.fileopenbox()
image_original = Image.open(image_path)

largeur, hauteur = image_original.size

image = resizeimage.resize_thumbnail(image_original, [300, 300]) 

output = io.StringIO()

image_nb = image.convert('L')

for y in range(hauteur):
    for x in range(largeur):
        value = image_nb.getpixel((x, y))
        if value < 64:
            output.write('@')

        elif value < 128:
            output.write('#')

        elif value < 192:
            output.write('/')
        else :
            output.write(',')
    output.write('\n')

with open('image finale.txt', mode='w') as f: 
    print(output.getvalue(), file=f)

webbrowser.open("image finale.txt")
```

Comment: You’ve resized the image but you are still trying to iterate over the original image dimensions.

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thanks Paul R,  I didn't see it and probably would never. :)